# Virtualbox busy, I have tried everything

Tags: boot, virtualbox

Helllo, I need help! pronto. some one decide to just grab my usb and not return it and now that I am trying to change distros but virtualbox says I cant because

busybox v1.27.2 (ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)

I have read all the blogs and I have followed all the youtube videos and I can't manage to fix it. I am about to give up on this. I don't have the usb with the ubuntu boot. I tried to make the directory and the whole mod766 and nothing.

Is there anything else I can do. Perhaps something more simple. I am extremely fed up with all of this right now. Any ones help is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Is the busybox prompt on the VM Host or on the VM Guest? What makes you believe that you need the USB to solve it? What is the error message immediately before the busybox prompt?

Comment: I am on a windows laptop with the VM installed on the lap trying to work the distro in the VM on the lap. the message appears when I boot up the distro to try to down load it. I get the boot menu and I press enter to start it. then it turns black and after about a min I get this 

https://prnt.sc/q08b56

Comment: Looks like you corrupted or otherwise mis-made your install .iso. Download it again from a reputable source (ubuntu.com/download). Insert the .iso into the Guest's virtual CD drive. Then boot the Guest.

Comment: Okay, so I should download it again and verify it again. Then go through and pace it in the VM. Should I delete everything and start from scratch? Look, I have window10 and I hate it. ever since vista it is horrible. I work on my computer and I have been researching Linux and I am really liking it. They hust came out with zorin lite and I think that that's the diztro for me because this is what I am working with.

https://prnt.sc/q08n0r

My comp isnt all that great but it gets shitt done.

Comment: Hold on, am I doing this with the new distro or the first one (Ubun)?

Comment: Seems like you might be overthinking this. Any new OS (like Zorin), will erase the old OS (Ubuntu) as part of the install process. Simply run the Zorin installer. If the Zorin installer fails, then ask Zorin support about it, because we don't know anything about Zorin.